# Proc SQL : Expecting a name , Case When, End AS

Tags: sas, case, proc-sql

While running the code mentioned below, I'm  getting the error "ERROR 22-322: Expecting a name." and the affected code is 'END AS "Z"'.  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this.

```
proc sql;
SELECT CASE
   WHEN REGION IS NULL THEN ZONE
   ELSE REGION
   END AS "Z",
```

Comment: I didn't realize you tagged with SAS.  Hopefully someone who knows this database can help you better +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS didn't recognise the column name as it is not correct syntax.  Your options are:

```
proc sql;
SELECT CASE
   WHEN REGION IS NULL THEN ZONE
   ELSE REGION
   END AS Z /* without quotes */
```

or

```
proc sql;
SELECT CASE
   WHEN REGION IS NULL THEN ZONE
   ELSE REGION
   END AS "Z"n /* as name literal */
```

I suggest the first approach as there is no need to make `Z` a literal (eg spaces, special chars etc).

Comment: It worked, I used the second with "Z"n as there were other column names with spaces like "Product Code". Thank you so much :)